# Prove inequality, when does equality hold? German Math Olympiad 2021, 2nd round

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers such that $a>b \geq 0$. Show that

$3a + \dfrac{4}{(a-b)^3} \geq 4 \sqrt{2}$

When does equality hold?

(German Math Olympiad 2021, 2nd round, Q4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$LHS = 3(a-b) +\dfrac{4}{(a-b)^3}+3b \ge 3(a-b) +\dfrac{4}{(a-b)^3} \tag{1}$$
Applying the AM-GM inequality for 3 times $(a-b)$ and $\dfrac{4}{(a-b)^3}$ to $(1)$, then

$$LHS \ge 4\sqrt[4]{(a-b)^3 \dfrac{4}{(a-b)^3} } = 4\sqrt{2} $$

The equality occurs if and only if  $b= 0$ and $a =\sqrt{2} $.

Comment: Oops, I'm very sorry, there was a typo in the numerator.

Comment: @spectre42 I see, so I changed the answer.

Comment: Thank you, how did you immediately see that AM-GM could work here?

Comment: @spectre42 I know this method at a very young age and have a lot of training with it. Practice makes perfect ;)

Comment: Ok, then more practice I guess :). And how did you calculate when equality occurs?

Comment: @spectre42 Exacly. And the equality occurs when $3b = 0$ and $(a-b) = \frac{4}{(a-b)^3}$ according to the AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c=a-b>0$ then we have to prove $$3b+3c + {4\over c^3}\geq 4\sqrt{2}$$

Now we have by AM-GM$(4)$ inequality for all positive $c$ $$c+c+c+{4\over c^3}\geq 4\sqrt[4]{c\cdot c\cdot c\cdot {4\over c^3}} = 4\sqrt{2}$$ with equality iff $c=\sqrt{2}$. So equaltiy is achieved iff $b=0$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$.